# Import packages to a project

Tags: android

when I want to import this : import ca.uol.aig.fftpack.RealDoubleFFT;
got an error. How can I import packages to a project?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder called **lib** in your project root folder. Just copy and paste the jar into that folder.

Right click the project-->properties-->Java Build Path-->Add Jars. Then add the jar as external library.